# Entity Framework makes query that includes a non-existent column then complains that it is not there

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-8.0

I have an app built on .net8.0.  I have created the following table in entity framework by scaffolding an existing database tables:

```
 public partial class Shipment1850 : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
     private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
     {
         Dirty = true;
         PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
     }

     [NotMapped]
     [JsonIgnore]
     public bool Dirty { get; set; } = false;

     private Guid _Id;
     public Guid Id
     {
         get
         {
             return _Id;
         }
         set
         {
             _Id = value;
             NotifyPropertyChanged();
         }
     }
     private int? _Idno;
     public int? Idno
     {
         get
         {
             return _Idno;
         }
         set
         {
             _Idno = value;
             NotifyPropertyChanged();
         }
     }
     private short? _Idsub;
     public short? Idsub
     {
         get
         {
             return _Idsub;
         }
         set
         {
             _Idsub = value;
             NotifyPropertyChanged();
         }
     }
     private int? _Unpacking;
     public int? Unpacking
     {
         get
         {
             return _Unpacking;
         }
         set
         {
             _Unpacking = value;
             NotifyPropertyChanged();
         }
     }
     private byte[] _CustSig;
     public byte[] CustSig
     {
         get
         {
             return _CustSig;
         }
         set
         {
             _CustSig = value;
             NotifyPropertyChanged();
         }
     }
     private DateTime? _CustSigDate;
     public DateTime? CustSigDate
     {
         get
         {
             return _CustSigDate;
         }
         set
         {
             _CustSigDate = value;
             NotifyPropertyChanged();
         }
     }
     private byte[] _Tspsig;
     public byte[] Tspsig
     {
         get
         {
             return _Tspsig;
         }
         set
         {
             _Tspsig = value;
             NotifyPropertyChanged();
         }
     }
     private DateTime? _TspsigDate;
     public DateTime? TspsigDate
     {
         get
         {
             return _TspsigDate;
         }
         set
         {
             _TspsigDate = value;
             NotifyPropertyChanged();
         }
     }
     private DateTime? _Modified;
     public DateTime? Modified
     {
         get
         {
             return _Modified;
         }
         set
         {
             _Modified = value;
             NotifyPropertyChanged();
         }
     }
     private string _ModifiedBy;
     public string ModifiedBy
     {
         get
         {
             return _ModifiedBy;
         }
         set
         {
             _ModifiedBy = value;
             NotifyPropertyChanged();
         }
     }
     private bool _Complete;
     public bool Complete
     {
         get
         {
             return _Complete;
         }
         set
         {
             _Complete = value;
             NotifyPropertyChanged();
         }
     }
     private string _UserName;
     public string UserName
     {
         get
         {
             return _UserName;
         }
         set
         {
             _UserName = value;
             NotifyPropertyChanged();
         }
     }
 }
```

and

```
public partial class Shipment1850Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        Dirty = true;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    [NotMapped]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public bool Dirty { get; set; } = false;

    private Guid _Id;
    public Guid Id
    {
        get
        {
            return _Id;
        }
        set
        {
            _Id = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private Guid? _S1850id;
    public Guid? S1850id
    {
        get
        {
            return _S1850id;
        }
        set
        {
            _S1850id = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private int? _InvNo;
    public int? InvNo
    {
        get
        {
            return _InvNo;
        }
        set
        {
            _InvNo = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private string _Item;
    public string Item
    {
        get
        {
            return _Item;
        }
        set
        {
            _Item = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private string _Description;
    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return _Description;
        }
        set
        {
            _Description = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private DateTime? _Modified;
    public DateTime? Modified
    {
        get
        {
            return _Modified;
        }
        set
        {
            _Modified = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private string _ModifiedBy;
    public string ModifiedBy
    {
        get
        {
            return _ModifiedBy;
        }
        set
        {
            _ModifiedBy = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Even though these tables are technically related, there is no foreign key constraint in the database.  I created an extension class to hold the items in the parent:

```
public partial class Shipment1850
{
    public List<Shipment1850Item> Items { get; set; }

}
```

when I make the following query:

```
   var id = Guid.Parse("5c059022-5b08-472e-b7fe-7ae9e4293d55");

   var s = await _context.Shipment1850Items
                   .Where(x => x.S1850id == id).ToListAsync();
```

I get the following error:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Error: Failed executing DbCommand (13ms) [Parameters=[@__id_0='?' (DbType = Guid)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [s].[ID], [s].[Description], [s].[InvNo], [s].[Item], [s].[Modified], [s].[ModifiedBy], [s].[S1850ID], [s].[Shipment1850Id]
FROM [Shipment1850Item] AS [s]
WHERE [s].[S1850ID] = @__id_0
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.1\System.Reflection.Metadata.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query: Error: An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'MPS_Tablet_Data.Entities.DispatchContext'.
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'Shipment1850Id'.
```

There is no column anywhere in my code or my database called Shipment1850Id.  For some reason it has decided to create this field.  If I comment out the:

```
   //public List<Shipment1850Item> Items { get; set; }
```

In the extension class, the error goes away.  I do this in similar tables and EF doesn't take it upon itself to create a non-existent foreign key.  Does anyone know how to make it quit doing this?

Comment: In future, please abide by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). All your `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation is irrelevant to the problem and having those long property implementations makes the code harder to read for no benefit.

Comment: Have you ever had a property with that name? I wonder whether it's actually executing an old build. If you do a *Find* for that text in your code, is it found anywhere?

Comment: Can you show us the relevant part of your `DbContext`?

Comment: It is not possible for a scaffold to produce such a model. It looks like you made changes to it after scaffolding. Check the context ```FluentApi``` for what there you have for the model

Comment: By adding `Items`, EF assumes (by convention) that there is a `Shipment1850Id` column. You have to override the convention by telling EF how the two tables are related, even if it's not by an actual FK constraint.

Comment: For those interested, I was able to generate the INotifyPropertyChanged in the scaffolding process using Handlebars.  You are, however, correct that it is not pertinent to this problem, but the code won't compile without it since some of my class extensions call NotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be quite simple.  Gert Arnold had the right idea.  In my extension class I just had to decorate the declaration for the Items property with a foreign key attribute.  Like so:

```
public partial class Shipment1850
{
    [ForeignKey("S1850id")]
    public ObservableCollection<Shipment1850Item> Items { get; set; }

}
```

Edit:
I discovered that:

```
public partial class Shipment1850
{
    [NotMapped]
    public ObservableCollection<Shipment1850Item> Items { get; set; }

}
```

will work as well...